# Implicit Intent

Tags: android-intent

I am new to android. I read about Implicit Intent from

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_26.html

Now my question is can I invoke my another application , as one of the activities ,in this applications through implicit intents ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. For example when you want to share from one app to another the image, 
you have to register in second app that receives the intent in the manifest file of that second app. The additional intent filter is below

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        **<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        **
    </activity>
```

then onCreate of second app that already has view with image view

```
ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
im.setImageURI((Uri) getIntent().getExtras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
```

It means that when you are declaring in manifest file the intent filter, whenever person will share the picture, your second app will come in the available list

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

Implicit intents do not name specific component, but instead declare a general action to perform, which allows a component from another app to handle it. For example, if you want to show the user a location on a map, you can use an implicit intent to request that another capable app show a specified location on a map.

Your activity sends a request to ActivityManager(which is a part of OS) then ActivityManager requests the activity from another application and then the response is sent from called application to you calling application.